# How to extract multiple values from Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

```
Util.ClearResults();
string tst = String.Join("", DateRange.Take(10).Select(d => d.DocHistory));
var matches = Regex.Matches (tst, "(?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,2}assigned by(?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,2}", RegexOptions.Multiline);
matches.Dump("Regex Matches");
foreach(var match in matches)
{
    match.Dump("Ind Match");
}
```

I have this code, and it seems to work properly grabbing "Value" and isn't breaking out specific values from that though:

I have strings like the following: "Request closed by Jack Arm on 08/16/2018,Assignee #1 James Arye assigned by Scotty Shep on 08/16/2018,Request submitted by Mac Weaver on 08/16/2018,Request created by Mac Weaver on 08/16/2018"

I'm attempting to extract the name to the left and to the right of "assigned by" but I'm getting "James Arye assigned by Scotty Shep"...is there a way to have it split out the "value" it found into 3 variables, with the regex?

Comment: Use capturing groups - [`((?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,2})assigned by((?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,2})`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%28%3f%3a%5ba-zA-Z%27-%5d%2b%5b%5ea-zA-Z%27-%5d%2b%29%7b0%2c2%7d%29assigned+by%28%28%3f%3a%5b%5ea-zA-Z%27-%5d%2b%5ba-zA-Z%27-%5d%2b%29%7b0%2c2%7d%29&i=Request+closed+by+Jack+Arm+on+08%2f16%2f2018%2cAssignee+%231+James+Arye+assigned+by+Scotty+Shep+on+08%2f16%2f2018%2cRequest+submitted+by+Mac+Weaver+on+08%2f16%2f2018%2cRequest+created+by+Mac+Weaver+on+08%2f16%2f2018) - and then `match.Groups[1].Value` and `match.Groups[2].Value` will hold the results.

Comment: Is the data on one line or multiple lines?

Comment: @jdweng The data can be over multiple lines

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew - Nicely done. That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew the "match.Groups[1].Value" is giving a compile error, that match does not contain "Groups"...any ideas anyone?

Comment: Are you sure you are iterating the matchcollection correctly? Try `foreach (Match match in matches) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use capturing groups around the parts you need to get:

```
((?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,2})assigned by((?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,2})
^ ---------- Group 1 ----------- ^           ^ ---------- Group 2-----------  ^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%28%3F%3A%5Ba-zA-Z%27-%5D%2B%5B%5Ea-zA-Z%27-%5D%2B%29%7B0%2C2%7D%29assigned%20by%28%28%3F%3A%5B%5Ea-zA-Z%27-%5D%2B%5Ba-zA-Z%27-%5D%2B%29%7B0%2C2%7D%29&i=Request%20closed%20by%20Jack%20Arm%20on%2008%2F16%2F2018%2CAssignee%20%231%20James%20Arye%20assigned%20by%20Scotty%20Shep%20on%2008%2F16%2F2018%2CRequest%20submitted%20by%20Mac%20Weaver%20on%2008%2F16%2F2018%2CRequest%20created%20by%20Mac%20Weaver%20on%2008%2F16%2F2018)

[image]

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/PLw6LZ):

```
var s = "Request closed by Jack Arm on 08/16/2018,Assignee #1 James Arye assigned by Scotty Shep on 08/16/2018,Request submitted by Mac Weaver on 08/16/2018,Request created by Mac Weaver on 08/16/2018";
var pattern = @"((?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,2})assigned by((?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,2})";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, pattern);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value.Trim());
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value.Trim());
}
```

Output:

```
James Arye
Scotty Shep
```